# Set Default Sorting For a Column using tablesorter

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter plugin for sorting by data in tables. I writing script as following:

```
$("#customerslist").tablesorter({ sortList: [[2, 0]] });
```

Here I am giving column sort for 2nd header till it is ok now.

But now I have added a new setting for this table that it will contains many columns for example customerid, datecreated, createdby, product, cost  etc. User may choose any of this columns that is for example user selects only customerid and datecreated to view in his table every time when opens this  he can only view this both columns. And he also set another setting that is when page is loaded he already save a setting that default to datecreated. So that when he opens the page it should be default sorting on datecreated but sorting should be available for customerid also.

All this values are get from database. So anyone can help how can I give sorting order according to column. Here all columns are will get dynamically all columns are may be view or not. Now I need to get as following:

```
$("#cutomerslist").tablesorter({ sortList: [[columnname, 0]] });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the class name or even the text within the header cell, then you can use that to find the correct column index ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1198/))

```
$(function(){
    var columnIndex = $('th:contains("age")').index();

    $('table').tablesorter({
        sortList : [[ columnIndex, 1 ]]
    });
});
```